# maximum number of players

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, airconsole

### If more than 2 players connect to the airconsole game, nothing in the controller.html code works.
how can ı fix this

### I did try more than 2 player connect the game and it not work.how can ı fix this

### Is there a maximum player limit? If so, how can I increase this limit?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit by default. The number of players that will be considered depends on what your screen defines when you call `setActivePlayers(numberOfPlayers)`.
Is it possible that you have code that uses `setActivePlayers(2)` like it is provided in the current pong game example?

Comment: I fixed this error. Now I need to set a maximum player limit because if I do not set a limit, more than 2 players can connect. Is there a way to limit the number of players?

Comment: For the game in the store: You configure that on https://airconsole.com/developers in your game.

In the game: There is no way at the time, you need to decide how to handle it. The common approach:

1. Using the AirConsole.instance.GetControllerDeviceIds() you can only handle the first X devices for visualisation on screen.

2. During gameplay: using setActivePlayers you will be able to identify the player number of a given device_id.  If a device_id does not have a player number, that means they are not part of the currently running game.